# Features & benefits of ngrx/store over reduxjs used in angular 2 app

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0, angular-redux

What are the advantage/disadvantage of using ngrx/store over reduxJs to implement data flow architecture in application developed using angular2+.
Also which one would be better for a large web application developed in angular2:
1. redux
2. ngrx/store
3 angular-redux

Could not find specific features each of these brings w.r.t. each other which could be helpful in developing complex application using angular2+.

Answer (score 0):

Both have their own benefits and solve the same problem. Ngrx uses Effects, angular-redux uses middleware so it might be possible to pick what you need from redux middleware.

Syntactically I prefer NGRX but it's just an opinion.

For large scale with complex needs I might go with angular-redux.